# Preventing the creation of a new instance of an Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest, media

I am developing an android music player app and i noticed that when i press the home button and open the app again it takes me to a new instance of the main activity, even when the music is playing.
My question is, is there any way i can prevent this from happening? I want to make it so that when pressing the application icon after it is already open, the first instance of the main activity is reopened without reloading?
I tried changing the launchMode on the manifest, as it says here: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html
Many thanks :)

Comment: launchmode singleTask

Comment: I tried singleInstance and it didnt work... Whats the difference?

Comment: `singleTop` reuses the instance only if already opened and in foreground, this mainly happens e.g. from a notification, `singleTask` always reuses the activity even if you pressed home